# algolia - trying to make a widget to filter an attribute that is a numerical range

Tags: filter, range, min, algolia, facet

Maybe it's not clear enough.
I use algolia to display bags.
The volume is an attribute.
The same bag exists in different volumes.
If the bag exists in 50l and 90l I would like the filter which is a slider to show my bag if it is set between 60 and 70 for instance.

In the CSV file I gave to algolia using the dashboard I wrote in my column volumes 50, 90. I tried 50-90
It seems not to be understood by algolia.

Does anyone know how I sould proceed to get this volume slider that would filter my bags correctly ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

ok I found the answer to my question :
In json format to write a range of numeric data I had to write like this :
volume_range: [50, 80]
algolia understand it perfectly and I can make a slider that works
Problem solved.